# How to sum a column when a flag is true for the same products

Tags: sql, databricks

I have the table below and I am not able to resolve this rule:

```
SELECT product_id,
       flag,
       SUM (stock) AS stock
  FROM stock_table
 WHERE product_id = 120104
 GROUP BY product_id,
          flag;

product_id flag stock
    120104    N    52
    120104    Y     3
```

If there is more than one identical `PRODUCT_ID` column and different `FLAG` column (**Y** and **N**):
These two lines (example) will become one, the `FLAG` will be = **Y** and the `STOCK` column will sum the values to **55**.

If you only have one `FLAG` (**Y** or **N**) for the same `PRODUCT_ID`, just sum the `STOCK` column.

I've tried to solve it with subqueries but I couldn't.

Comment: Please don’t link to images, add all relevant information to your question as editable text. Show the table definitions, sample data and the result you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT product_id,
       MAX (flag) AS flag,
       SUM (stock) AS stock
  FROM stock_table
 WHERE product_id = 120104
 GROUP BY product_id;

product_id flag stock
    120104    Y    55
```

Whenever it's just a single flag for the product it will stay as is and when there are both `N` and `Y` it will become `max('N', 'Y') = 'Y'`.